# Frameworks for optimizing performance with Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

This is kind of an unusual situation so forgive me for the odd title. I've been looking at optimizing an HTML interface for manipulating server data. All data is passed over a REST service and there are existing jQuery methods for pulling and submitting the data.

The problem is that all this runs very slowly due to the large amount of Javascript code used for animating and manipulating the screen. Obviously I can optimize the javascript code to some extent, but the interface is so slow I'm wondering if there are other frameworks I should look at taking advantage of. I don't have the ability to leverage anything server side like PHP.

If there are no other frameworks, I'm planning to move most of the code to jQuery to improve readability and take advantage of the optimizations others have done there.

Comment: http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas - especially #9 - Stop touching the DOM, damnit!

Comment: This is sort of impossible to answer without at least a small snippet of what your code looks like.

Comment: Frameworks aren't about performance, their about maintainability of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at AngularJS. It is a framework (by Google) specifically designed for data driven websites. It is built on jQuery. It provides a $resource service which can be used to develop your own REST client for your website. The purpose of which is to enhance code readability and performance by abstracting the lower-level HTTP calls.

You can also have a look at Dojo but it has a huge learning curve.

Comment: Can't speak about Angular, but I definitely wouldn't say Dojo is built for performance

Comment: Please run the tests for yourself:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-dojo-vs-mootools-dom/42

But ofcourse, some frameworks/libraries are going to be better than others in one thing or another. But I was addressing the maintainability, readability AND performance issue in the question, not just performance.

Comment: What about the latest version of that test? http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-dojo-vs-mootools-dom/134 (I suspect jQuery and mootools are just deferring to the built-in QSA, but why doesn't Dojo do this?)

Comment: Here's another test with my own little homegrown query selector, which blows the others away: http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-dojo-vs-mootools-dom/135 -- I've made a homegrown knockoff of dojo's `declare` which similarly outperforms dojo, and with less cruft, plus it's cleaner. Again, I wouldn't say dojo is built for speed (or any of these GP libraries really)

Comment: I agree that Dojo isn't built "only" for speed. And as I said that jQuery (or another library/framework) might outperform Dojo in some regards. But jQuery is a library and Dojo is a framework. You can always build a framework over a library but hey, sometimes it's just not worth investing that much time and effort. That's where a framework comes in. And that is what Dojo is. But I personally like AngularJS better myself. And it is a framework built on top of jQuery. So you are right where you are, but I wasn't "only" addressing the problem you are picking me on. :-).

Comment: Fair enough. I was hoping to see an answer more along the lines of "shopping for frameworks is not an appropriate way to optimize for performance," but I guess that's expecting too much. ;)

Comment: Of course, if you are very confident of your programming skills then noting beats creating the app from scratch. But frameworks do ensure your apps performance by imposing good practices on you.